# Is my guess and substitution approach to solving this recursion problem correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, recurrence-relations, recursion

I think I solved this recurrence relation problem but I am not sure if my answer is correct. Can you please help me?

```
n >= 1 is a power of 2 integer
T(1) = 0
T(n) = T(n/2) + 100

My approach

T(2) = T(1) + 100 = 100
T(4) = T(2) + 100 = 200
T(8) = T(4) + 100 = 300
T(16)= T(8) + 100 = 400

I guessed the solution to be 100 * Log(n)

By induction I attempted to prove it

T(n) = 100 log(n/2) + 100
     = 100 log(n) + 100
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `n >= 1 is a power of 2 integer` Let $n=2^{k}$ then $T(2^k) = T(2^{k-1})+100\,$, so $Q(k)=T(2^k)$ is an airthmetic progression.

Comment: This is a good approach, and indeed, it is an intuitive way to solve recurrence relations.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  - is my answer correct though?

Comment: Yes, it is @Avi

Comment: The derivation in the last line has a typo: it certainly isn't the case that $\log(n/2) = \log n$.